# Recovering a file from a pulled flash drive

Tags: linux, gedit

So I made a HUGE mistake and pulled a flash drive while i had a text file open in gedit. When I opened the text file later, it was completely empty. Is there any way that I can recover it from RAM, or some tmp directory somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The temporary file might still exist so check for that first (could be hidden):

```
cat /path/file~
```

If not, it's likely not going to be found on the disk anymore. You might be able to partially recover the file from memory depending on what you've been doing. Get the PID of your gedit process and do a dump (1234 is an example pid below).

```
ps -ef | grep gedit
sudo gcore 1234
sudo vi core.1234
```

Good luck!